# HTTP Cache-Control and params order

Tags: http, caching, cache-control

Why browsers cache data, don't send request to server, **only** if query parameters in url are in same order?

For example if request to

> /product?q=phone&cat=1

send in response header *Cache-Control:max-age=60*

the next request

> /product?cat=1&q=phone

request is send to server, but should retrieve data from cache

Also some frameworks recommend

> If you are caching requests that use a large number of query string
>   parameters, consider sorting them to ensure that the request is
>   properly cached.
>
> By ordering your params, you can be sure the cache
>   key will be consistent across requests and you are caching
>   effectively.

Comment: This is related to server side logic. You need to check why `Cache-Control` header presents in one request but not in another.

Comment: I updated. Te question is why second request is not retrieving data from cache?

Answer (score 8):

HTTP doesn't define the syntax of query parameters. So from the cache's point of view, these URLs might identify different content.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [HTTP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234), the primary key for cache is URI:

> The primary cache key consists of the request method and target URI. However, since HTTP caches in common use today are typically limited to caching responses to GET, many caches simply decline other methods and **use only the URI as the primary cache key**.

Thus, all cache related headers: `Cache-Control`, `Expires`, `ETag` etc. are all based on one precondition: resource of the same URL.

Comment: Are the query parameters considered part of the URL or URI?

Comment: The characters of query parameters are considered part of URI. However, as Julian Reschke stated, it's only treated as normal characters.